# Creating custom user profile section programmatically

Tags: access

Here when I am creating a new custom section it is showing an error as Adding a property definition requires Manage User Profiles rights in the code

```
CoreProperty cp = cpm.Create(true);
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("localhost");
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
UserProfileConfigManager upcm = new UserProfileConfigManager(context);

ProfilePropertyManager ppm = upcm.ProfilePropertyManager;

CorePropertyManager cpm = ppm.GetCoreProperties();

if (cpm.GetSectionByName(propertyname) == null)
{
       **CoreProperty cp = cpm.Create(true);**
       cp.Name = propertyname;
       cp.DisplayName = displayname;
       cpm.Add(cp);

       ProfileTypePropertyManager ptpm = ppm.GetProfileTypeProperties(ProfileType.User);
       ProfileTypeProperty ptp = ptpm.Create(cp);
       ptpm.Add(ptp);

       ProfileSubtypeManager psm = ProfileSubtypeManager.Get(context);
       ProfileSubtype ps = psm.GetProfileSubtype(ProfileSubtypeManager.GetDefaultProfileName(ProfileType.User));

       ProfileSubtypePropertyManager pspm = ps.Properties;
       ProfileSubtypeProperty psp = pspm.Create(ptp);
       pspm.Add(psp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a pemission problem.

Run your code in elevated privileges, like this:

```
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            SPUser AdminUser = sitefeature.RootWeb.AllUsers[@"SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM"];
            var superToken = AdminUser.UserToken;
            HttpContext con = HttpContext.Current;

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(sitefeature.Url, superToken))
                {
                   // create custom property code here
                }
            });

            HttpContext.Current = con;
```